# UTL_FILE.FOPEN ORA-20102: Invalid Operation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to use `UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_DIR','test.txt','W');`

but I get the following error :

> ORA-20102: Invalid Operation

I tried to put READ and WRITE on 'MY_DIR' to the public like this:

`GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY MY_DIR to public;`

It changes nothing!

I gave all rights on `MY_DIR` (`chmod 777 /test_data`), the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server directory path `'MY_DIR'` has either no `write` permission or may some other unknow issue(since you said you already gave 777 permission).

When you create a directory in Oracle using `Create directory` command, you are automatically granted the `READ` and `WRITE` object privileges on the `directory`, and you can grant these privileges to other `users` and `roles`. Same you can check as below.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM all_tab_privs 
 WHERE table_name = <Your directory>;  --> You would see that all the priv is there and still you cannot open the file.
```

See below demo:

```
SQL> create or replace  directory  BDUMP as '/app/home/user/fil_test/';

Directory created.

SQL> SELECT * 
  FROM all_tab_privs 
 WHERE table_name = 'BDUMP';     


SQL> /

GRANTOR              GRANTEE              TABLE_SCHEMA           TABLE_NAME            PRIVILEGE    GRA  HIE
------------------ ----------------  --------------- --------------- ------------------ --- ----    ---  ---
SYS                  USER                       SYS               BDUMP                 EXECUTE      YES NO
SYS                  USER                       SYS               BDUMP                 READ         YES NO
SYS                 USER                        SYS               BDUMP                 WRITE        YES NO
```

-- Anonymous block to write a file.

```
SQL> DECLARE
    fHandle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
 BEGIN
   fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('BDUMP', 'test_file', 'w');

   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the first line');
      UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the second line');
      UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (fHandle, 'This is the third line');

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fHandle);
    EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
         'Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
          RAISE;
    END;  
  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation  <--- error your get
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 16
```

In the above demo you saw that even if you created the directory and try to write a file you are not able to. Reason behind this is server directory permission. See below:

```
aixserver:user$ ls -lrt
dr-xr-xr-x   2 t541682  dev            2 Oct  9 10:06 fil_test
```

Here when i created the directory manually, i just gave `execute` permission.

Now i changed the permission :

```
aixserver:user$ chmod 777 fil_test
aixserver:user$ ls -lrt
drwxrwxrwx   2 t541682  dev            2 Oct  9 10:06 fil_test
```

I now execute the same PLSQL block to write to a file and i get below:

```
SQL> DECLARE
   fHandle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  BEGIN
   fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('BDUMP', 'test_file', 'w');

   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the first line');
   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the second line');
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (fHandle, 'This is the third line');

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fHandle);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
         'Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
      RAISE;
END; 
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

And i check on unix server for file created now as:

```
aixserver:user$ pwd
/app/home/user/fil_test
aixserver:user$ $ ls -lrt
total 2
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba           68 Oct  9 10:26 test_file
```

I now see the file created.

Comment: Thank you XING for your help. I have exactly the error you mentioned above, I gave all rights to the directory (chmod -R 777 /test_data) but I still get the same error again and again and again. the privileges are like you said by default READ WRITE and EXECUTE on My_DIR!!

Comment: Use `chmod  777 test_data` to give permission to your directory and try. I already showed in my example. Just follow each step and you should succeed then,

Comment: This is exactly what I did XING, but it still gave me the error:29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.

Comment: `An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does not exist,` Does this mean the directory you are referring not exist. Have you checked that using the query i posted above.Check & verify ..!!

Comment: I've checked and verified it, it tells us that MY_DIR-which is test_data exists and has exactly READ WRITE and EXECUTE privileges for the current user with whom I'm trying to use UTL_FILE, and also this directory exists on system file with 777 rights

Comment: @Mac. this is pretty strange because same i did on my system and it worked fine. Can you try changing creating a new directory.

Comment: Hi @XING, the problem is the database is created on a separate server than the one from which I access to the database! so I wasn't creating the directory on the server in which database exists!